# vgcreate --> "Command failed with status code 5." what does this mean?

Tags: centos, xen, lvm

i'm playing around w/ LVM on a centos domU in a xen-based vps.  I'm in rescue mode and I've created one physical volume (*pvcreate /dev/xvda1*) for my entire drive, which is formatted as LVM.  i'm now trying to create a volume group using *vgcreate main /dev/xvda1*, but it's returning "Command failed with status code 5.".  I've been unable to find an explanation for this error code.  does anyone know what it means?

for what it's worth, my goal is to create multiple logical volumes on my drive using lvm.

thanks

Comment: You mean that the partition type is LVM, right?

Comment: What happens when you type "pvdisplay"?

Comment: thank for the help, Matt.  yes, the partition type is lvm.  running pvdisplay outputs (this displays badly, so I'm using | to denote an endline):
  "/dev/xvda1" is a new physical volume of "6.00 GB" | 
  --- NEW Physical volume --- | 
  PV Name               /dev/xvda1 | 
  VG Name               | 
  PV Size               6.00 GB | 
  Allocatable           NO | 
  PE Size (KByte)       0 | 
  Total PE              0 | 
  Free PE               0 | 
  Allocated PE          0 | 
  PV UUID               sMR01N-ZFqb-Us3J-IhMj-FI1V-WjdV-r70yhQ |

Comment: found this: 
http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/lvm_10/vgcreate
it says "5 (denotes) maximum number of volume groups exceeded", but vgscan shows nothing

Comment: Poor formatting in comments is why you're supposed to edit your question to add information like that.

Comment: `vgcreate -d main /dev/bla` -the -d flag will give you debugging into.

Answer (score 6):

I was having this same problem with a CentOS recovery disc on a Xen system. Turns out the error code is due to a read-only file system, specifically `/etc/lvm` is read-only. Quick fix, as suggested by [this blog entry](http://rodrigodc.net/blog/?p=16), is to create a tmpfs over `/etc/lvm` to enable writing. This worked for me.

Comment: If the blog post link is not working (like it doesn't for me), you can do that as   `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /etc/lvm`

Answer (score 2):

from the comments it looks like your pv is already corrupt: `Total PE 0`. recreate your pv and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, try:

```
vgcreate -v main /dev/xvda1
```

To get more idea of what is going wrong. In my case, the error occurred because /etc/lvm wasn't writeable to create backups.

Comment: In my case the problem was read only partition with `/etc/lvm/`. `vgcreate` failed when it was trying to write `/etc/lvm/archive`.

Answer (score 0):

Christion is certainly right. In addition, you can probably start playing with lvm using [system-config-lvm](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-system-config-lvm.html), before going deeper with the command-line (of course, not in rescue mode).