# pvcreate and lvcreate fail with return code 5

Tags: linux, lvm

I am trying to use `pvcreate` to create a physical volume and then use `lvcreate` to create a logical volume on Centos7.9. But, both `pvcreate` and `lvcreate` seem to be failing with error code 5.

`/bin/lvm pvcreate -y -ff /dev/md7,/dev/md8,/dev/md12` returned 5
...
`/bin/lvm lvcreate -y -L 16GB -n home group`B returned 5
I read elsewhere in the post: [vgextend fails with error code 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/285499/vgextend-fails-with-error-code-5)
about `vgextend` failing due to root partition being mounted read-only.
But, I have verified that it is not so in this case.
Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Well, just exit code and no output to the terminal?

Comment: No. It just prints the exit code.

Comment: Try to make it verbose with `-v` to `-vvvv` and with `-d` to `-dddddd`. Just "exit code" probably isn't enough to know what's going on.

Comment: have you checked this https://serverfault.com/questions/100736/vgcreate-command-failed-with-status-code-5-what-does-this-mean, also error 5 mean `error getting status of logical volume` check the local volume first before creating.